# how to get output of code in a txt file?

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have been trying to get console output to a text file but what I get is output of only one recursion.
I am calling the function with different parameters but the output will be printed in the file just once, not for all recursions.
Please help.

```
     File file = new File("out.txt");
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
     PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
     System.setOut(ps);
     System.out.println("Mean is : "+meanX);
     System.out.println("Variance is :"+ variance);
     System.out.println("Standard Deviation is :"+std_deviation);
     System.out.println("CoVariance is :"+covariance);
     System.out.println("CoRelation is :"+corel);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not showing the complete program I can only guess that that code is inside of the function you mentioned that you are calling with different parameters.  If that is the case then create the `FileOutputStream` with **append mode**: `FileOutputStream("out.txt", true);`

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize your OutputStream with the constructor that takes an append flag:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

This way whenever you open the file again, the new data will be added without removing the current data in the file.

I have just tested it and it works fine.